# Custom SC_Error_Code Siebel CTI 2015

Tags: crm, siebel

I need to register a custom error code while creating custom driver for *Siebel CTI*. As per its document, following errors are predefined (enum from `scapi.h`):

```
enum SCErrorCode
{
    SC_EC_OK = 0,
    SC_EC_ERROR = 1,
    SC_EC_CMD_NOT_SUPPORTED = 2,
    SC_EC_MEDIA_TYPE_NOT_SUPPORTED = 3,
    SC_EC_INVALID_HANDLE = 4,
    SC_EC_OUT_OF_MEMORY = 5,
    SC_EC_NETWORK_ERROR = 6,
    SC_EC_LIB_LOAD_ERR = 7,     /* Unable to load driver DLL          */
    SC_EC_FUNC_NOT_RESOLVED = 8,     /* Unable to resolve function address */
    SC_EC_DRIVER_CREATION_ERR = 9,
    SC_EC_DRIVER_RELEASE_ERR = 10,
    SC_EC_SERVICE_CREATION_ERR = 11,
    SC_EC_SERVICE_RELEASE_ERR = 12,
    SC_EC_INVALID_ITEM_TRACKING_ID = 13,
    SC_EC_CLIENT_INTERFACE_ERR = 14,    /* Failed on invoking ISC_CLIENT_HANDLE function       */
    SC_EC_SENDMSG_FAILED_RETRY = 15,    /* SC_CT_SENDMESSAGE failed,  please resend again later  */
    SC_EC_IMPOBJ_CREATE_ERR = 16,    /* Unable to create the underlying implementation object */
    SC_EC_INVALID_LICENSE = 17,
    SC_EC_WORK_ITEM_WRONG_STATE = 18,    /* Work item is at wrong state for the operation         */
    SC_EC_DRIVER_SPECIFIC = 1000
};
```

Siebel Administration guide [page 270](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14004_01/books/PDF/SiebCTIAdm.pdf#G13.1004800) says:

**SCErrorCode:**
*The values enumerated by SCErrorCode specify predefined error codes. The error codes from 0 to 1000 are reserved.*

How can I add/register a custom error code? Or is there any way to specify driver specific error message using `SC_EC_DRIVER_SPECIFIC` error.